# Design looks perfect in Chrome, destroyed in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flash, google-chrome, firefox

Have designed and coded a website using CSS and HTML. When viewing in Google Chrome everything looks fine, but Firefox is a different story. Also looks fine using IE except for the Flash banner.

http://www.readthetape.com

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please avoid question that have no problem shown inline in the question. Your post will make no sense as soon as you fix your site. Please either inline problem portions of layout into the question OR keep whatever site linked from the question up in broken state forever.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the browsers has slightly different settings for margins etc.  You shoudl either use a reset css to remove or set them all to zero or user vendor specific code such as -webkit- and -moz- etc for any css3 effect.  Maybe that'll help.

Comment: I had to get in quick with that one :)

Answer (score 0):

its because swf is not loading in firefox

you should `embed` method for calling the swf file

like

```
<embed src="main.swf" width="550" height="400" wmode="transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox isn't loading the SWF because you have a typo in the filename, and a missing quote:

```
<embed src=images/banner.swf3" width="850" height="180"> </embed>
```

Instead of

```
<embed src="images/banner3.swf" width="850" height="180"> </embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will also point out that you have several html errors. Use a validator such as http://validator.w3.org/ or install a browser plugin that does html validation. Using valid html will often prevent many of these cross browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

You must always clear your floats...

Try adding

`clear:both`

to your maincontent div